# How can I install Google Play Store on Ubuntu Mobile

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu Touch on Samsung Note4.

I need to install some program of Google play store.

How can I install Android apps from **Google Play Store** on Ubuntu Mobile?

Or, how can I install Google Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

Natively Ubuntu Touch doesn't run Android applications. Ubuntu Touch is it's own OS, not a flavour of Android. However on some devices it's possible to run android inside a container, due to Anbox, and install and android apps on it.

The Samsung Note4 is not currently a device where you can use anbox.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch Focal, comes with [Waydroid](https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/waydroid.html) in which you can add the [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) appstore from which you can install [Aurora Store: A Google Playstore Client](https://auroraoss.com) and then install the apps you want.

From the Ubports, Waydroid and Aurora pages:

> Waydroid is a minimal Android container and compatibility layer to run
> Android apps on GNU/Linux operating systems such as Ubuntu Touch.
>
> How to set up
>
> All Halium 9 and newer devices ship with waydroid out of
> the box starting with Ubuntu Touch focal, if your device fits these
> requirements you can follow the following steps:
>
> 1. Open a shell on your Ubuntu Touch device (remotely with ADB/SSH or
>    locally with the terminal app).
> 2. Run the following command in your shell: waydroid init.
> 3. Done! You might have to refresh the apps scope (pull down from the
>    center of the screen and release) for the new Android apps to show up.
>
> Using an appstore in Waydroid
>
> You install an appstore like F-Droid or Amazon Appstore to install applications or keeping them up to date.
>
> Aurora Store (available in F-Droid appstore) is an unofficial, FOSS client to Google's Play Store with an elegant design. Not only does Aurora Store download, update, and search for apps like the Play Store, it also empowers the user with new features.
>
> For those concerned with privacy, Aurora Store does not require
> Google's proprietary framework (spyware?) to operate. It works
> perfectly fine with or without Google Play Services or MicroG.

Just be sure that [Ubuntu Touch runs on your device](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can not install apps from Google Play Store on Ubuntu Touch, nor can you install google play on Ubuntu touch.
You can install a VPN on Ubuntu Touch, following this guide https://ubports.com/blog/ubports-news-1/post/vpn-on-ubuntu-touch-3022.
I do not know how well Ubuntu Touch is supported on the Samsung Note 4.